# How Do I Set The ChromeDriver Version I Want To Use On Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am running RobotFramework tests on Jenkins which has been fine until recently. There is now a mismatch in ChromeDriver and Chromium Versions. Initially the error was ChromeDriver would only work with Chrome 83, so I upgraded it the latest 86. Now I'm getting a new error as follows.

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only 
supports Chrome version 86
Current browser version is 85.0.4183.83 with binary path /usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

So I have gone too far with my ChromeDriver Version now it seems. Does anyone know how to upgrade chromium-browser to 86 or downgrade ChromeDriver to 85 in JENKINS. I will take either. I am not using Docker just incase you think it might an image issue.

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads